# How to search for a row(s) with varying search data (Some given, Some not)

Tags: python, sqlite

I use SQL statements to search for rows in my database depending on given data. if the columns are (ID,Username,Password,Clearance,Class_Count) then my program will sometimes only search for the username, or the clearance. But sometimes it will search for both the username and the class count. I am unaware of any ways in which I can easily implement this into my code without creating (I believe) about 7 different IF statements to check which data is being used to search (Examples will be given in the below code)

```
def Get_Users_DB(self, Search_Data):
    Details_Dic = Create_User_Dict((None,Search_Data[0],None,Search_Data[1],Search_Data[2]))
    try:  # Defensive programming to prevent database errors from stopping the program from running
        with global_lock:
            if Details_Dic["Username"]:
                # If a username is given, no other values need to be checked as username are unique
                self.DB_Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE username = ?", (Details_Dic["Username"],))
                # Selects user from USERS table based on the username provided
                User_Data = self.DB_Cursor.fetchall()
                # Fetches the user if applicable, returns as a list for processing purposes

            elif Details_Dic["Clearance"] and Details_Dic["Class_Count"] is not None:
                print("Here b0ss")
                # If there is a value for clearance and Class_Count is not a none type
                self.DB_Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE\
                                       clearance = ? AND Class_Count = ?",
                                       (Details_Dic["Clearance"], Details_Dic["Class_Count"]))
                # Select all users based on these restrictions
                User_Data = self.DB_Cursor.fetchall()

            elif Details_Dic["Clearance"]:  # If only a clearance level is given
                self.DB_Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE\
                                       clearance = ?", (Details_Dic["Clearance"],))
                User_Data = self.DB_Cursor.fetchall()
            elif Details_Dic["Class_Count"] is not None:  # If only a class value is given
                self.DB_Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE\
                                       Class_Count = ?", (Details_Dic["Class_Count"],))
                User_Data = self.DB_Cursor.fetchall()
            else:  # If no values are given, get all users
                self.DB_Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS")
                User_Data = self.DB_Cursor.fetchall()

        if User_Data:  # If any value was returned from the database
            User_Dict_List = []
            for User_Details in User_Data:  # For every user in the list convert them to a dictionary
                User_Dict = Create_User_Dict(User_Details)
                User_Dict_List.append(User_Dict)
            return User_Dict_List
        else:
            return False  # Tell called from function that the user does not exist

    except sqlite3.Error as Err:  # If an error occurs display a message in the console
        Error_Report(Err, "Get_User_DB")
        return False  # Tell called from function that the function was unsuccessful
```

From this program I basically want a more streamlined way of checking for what data is given, and what I need to query my database with

Edit:
I have now tried a method provided:

```
def Create_Where_Condition(self, Details_Dic):
    print("In Where Condition")
    Where_Condition = ""
    for Key, Value in Details_Dic.items():
        print("Key:",Key)
        print("Value:", Value)
        if Value is not None:
            Prefix = " AND " if Where_Condition else " WHERE "
            Where_Condition += Prefix + "{}={}".format(Key, Value)
    return Where_Condition

def Get_Users_DB(self,Search_Data):
    print("In get_user_db")
    Details_Dic = Create_User_Dict((None, Search_Data[0], None, Search_Data[1], Search_Data[2]))
    print("after details_dic")
    SQL_Statement = "SELECT * FROM USERS" + self.Create_Where_Condition(Details_Dic)
    print("SQL STATEMENT:\n{}".format(SQL_Statement))
    try:  # Defensive programming to prevent database errors from stopping the program from running
        with global_lock:
            self.DB_Cursor.execute(SQL_Statement)
            User_Data = self.DB_Cursor.fetchall()
            print(User_Data)
        if User_Data:  # If any value was returned from the database
            User_Dict_List = []
            for User_Details in User_Data:  # For every user in the list convert them to a dictionary
                User_Dict = Create_User_Dict(User_Details)
                User_Dict_List.append(User_Dict)
            return User_Dict_List
        else:
            return False  # Tell called from function that the user does not exist

    except sqlite3.Error as Err:  # If an error occurs display a message in the console
        Error_Report(Err, "Get_User_DB")
        return False  # Tell called from function that the function was unsuccessful
```

However now I get the error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: foo
```

where 'foo' is the username I am searching for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your dictionary keys don't match the case of your table columns.
If you could change that, you could create a function which creates there `WHERE` condition for you:

```
def create_where_condition(details_dic):
    where_condition = ""
    for key, value in details_dic.items():
        if value is not None:
            prefix = " AND " if where_condition else " WHERE "
            where_condition += prefix + '{}="{}"'.format(key, value)
    return where_condition

create_where_condition({"username": "Tom", "clearance": None, "Class_Count": 10})  # -> ' WHERE username=Tom AND Class_Count=10'
create_where_condition({"username": "Tom", "clearance": 100, "Class_Count": 10})  # -> ' WHERE username=Tom AND clearance=100 AND Class_Count=10'
create_where_condition({"username": None, "clearance": None, "Class_Count": None})  # -> ''
```

This approach has the benefit that it will scale if you want to include more rows in the WHERE clause without having to add additional `if`/`elif` statements.

If your details_dic also contains other keys that do not correspond to columns in your table or that you do not like to be included in the WHERE clause, you can add a whitelist as second parameter:

```
def create_where_condition(details_dic, rows_to_include):
    where_condition = ""
    for key, value in details_dic.items():
        if key in rows_to_include and value is not None:
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value = '"' + value + '"'
            prefix = " AND " if where_condition else " WHERE "
            where_condition += prefix + '{}={}'.format(key, value)
    return where_condition
```

Comment: I have attempted your method, however whenever i execute the statement (I add 'SELECT * FROM TABLE') it tells me that 'input_username' is not a column.

Comment: That's what I meant with the first paragraph. If you want to use this function, you will have to change your dictionary keys to match the name of your columns. I see you added my function to your start post and get an error for a key "foo", which means you should also include a whitelist as in my second implementation.

Comment: I did though. Why is it taking the 'foo' part as a column anyways, if username is the name of the column, why would 'foo' be used?

Comment: Aka my dictionary is {"Username":"Foo"}

Comment: I found out what the error is. In the code you gave me, if the value is a string, it has no quotation marks around it, so that means that a string value will be taken as a column

Comment: So I need to find a way so that any string values have extra quotation marks put around them

Comment: You beat me by a minute. I updated the answer right now. My bad.

Comment: That doesn't work either, as integer values would then be counted as strings. So I added another if statement 'If isinstance(Value,str): Value = "'" + Value + "'"

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I rejected your proposed edit before reading your comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: Good stuff, I can select it as the answer now. Not the any of the other solutions are bad, but this is the one I used

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? Make the query a string and a params list that are built with the `if` clauses, then you can code one execute/fetch. The thought is something like this in pseudo code:

```
query = "SELECT * from users WHERE 1 = 1"  
if username then query += "AND username = ?", params.push[username]  
else  
   if clearance then query += "AND clearance = ?", params.push[clearance]  
   if class_count then query += "AND class_count =?",params.push[class_count] 
execute(query,params)
```

The `WHERE 1 = 1` is used so the original query will run and select all rows when no params are supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that with the help of f strings (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and ternary operators:

```
def query_users(self, search_data):
    details_dict = create_user_dict((None, search_data[0], None, search_data[1], search_data[2]))
    with global_lock:
        # Named parameters in query looks like this %(<named_param>)s
        sql_query = f"""
        SELECT * from USERS WHERE 1=1
        {"AND username=%(username)s" if details_dict.get("username") else ""}
        {"AND clearance=%(clearance)s" if details_dict.get("clearance") else ""}
        {"AND Class_Count=%(class_count)s" if details_dict.get("class_count") else ""};
        """
        # Execute methods provides possibility of using named parameters which are already in the details_dict
        self.db_cursor.execute(sql_query, details_dict)
    except sqlite3.Error as Err:
        Error_Report(Err, "Get_User_DB")
        return False
```

Or if your DB column names matches the key names in the details_dict you can try this approach:

````
    details_dict = create_user_dict((None, search_data[0], None, search_data[1], search_data[2]))
    with global_lock:
        sql_query = f"""
        SELECT * from USERS WHERE 1=1
        """
        # We can interpolate strings using dictionary keys
        for field_name in details_dict.keys():
            sql_query += f" AND {field_name}=%({field_name})s "
        self.db_cursor.execute(sql_query, details_dict)
    except sqlite3.Error as Err:
        Error_Report(Err, "Get_User_DB")
        return False```
````